# Body is not getting parsed in GET method

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, express, mockoon

I am using mockoon for API simulation. I created 2 routes there with method GET and its body contains(responds with) JSON object. I noticed that my express app is not able to parse one of the routes. But the route that has JSON object in body which contains ARRAY is getting parsed. I tested both routes with Express(by console.log) and in chrome browser(I have JSON formatter extension) and it is behaving the same meaning response that does not contain ARRAY is not getting parsed but the response with array is getting parsed(behaving normally). Let me show the screenshots:

 Express(by console.log):

 With array: [image]

 Without array: [image]

Chrome(JSON Formatter extension):

 With array(extension is able to parse): [image]

 Without array(extension is not able to parse): [image]

I tried adding Header(Content-Type: application/json) to the route in mockoon. But still, I am not aware of what is going on here. Someone please explain

The express code:

```
const iabs_client = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:3001/iabs-client
  );
```

Here is the route created in Mockoon(without array inside JSON):
[image]

P.S mockoon is a program that creates endpoints in localhost, useful for API simulation when developing front-end without having backend yet

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but it looks like one is a JavaScript object and the other is JSON. Can you show the code that's producing this output?

Comment: I don't think we can help without seeing the relevant code.  If express isn't parsing it as JSON when that's the intended data type and other JSON is parsed fine, then apparently there is something wrong with this particular request that causes Express to not see it as JSON.

Comment: @kevintechie I am doing simple get request with axios, nothing special there. I am also using express.json middleware. I will add the code to the question

Comment: @jfriend00 I edited the question by adding the express code. But honestly, i think this issue has to do with Mockoon probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing comma after "something" is not valid JSON. Edit your Mockoon body to remove the comma and it should work.

Comment: OMG, thank you. such an embarrassment(

Comment: No problem, sometimes it's the smallest things!